# Time control of a submit button

Tags: php, forms

**gustavotkg** shared the following piece of his knowledge recently in response to a query about preventing visitors submitting multiple enteries to a file. He suggested as follows:

> "If you disable the submit button in the onclick event, the visitor
>   will have to refresh the page for resubmitting your form".
>
> You can do something like:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("button-id");
btn.onclick = function() {
    btn.disabled = 'disabled';
}
```

Disabling the button provides a temporary solution and indeed it appears that multiple enteries are difficult to prevent.

Can this temporary 
solution as suggested by **gustavotkg** be aided by further enabling the **Submit Button** to be disabled for a **time 
period** of say a week or 168hrs?

Comment: You *could* disable the submit button through JavaScript by setting a cookie, but it's easily bypassed. A better solution is to identify your users (by logging them in, by IP address, etc.) and recording when each one submits an entry.

Comment: Could a Submit button be scripted to self destruct or become inoperable after sending a single entry?

Comment: Yes, when the user sends a single entry, you can set a cookie that signifies a submission. When the user clicks the button, in the `onclick` attribute of the button, you would check if the cookie exists. If it does, that means the user already submitted an entry, and you shouldn't let them submit another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example demonstrating the desired functionality.

A cookie is set with an expiration date of 7 days. When the button is clicked, the onclick event checks if the cookie is set, if it is, it denies the submission by returning false. Otherwise, the function sets the cookie and allows the submission to go through.

**PLEASE NOTE** that this is **not** going to guarantee anything, as any (non-novice) user can delete their cookies and resubmit an entry.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Thanks to http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}    
</script>

<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input id="button-id" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var btn = document.getElementById("button-id");
btn.onclick = function() {
    var cookie_name = 'submitted_entry';
    btn.disabled = 'disabled';
    if( readCookie( cookie_name))
    {
        alert( 'You can not submit an entry again!');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        createCookie( cookie_name, 1, 7);
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: This will help manage the non-novice inputs. I can check manually for multiple inputs but the above should help reduce the workload. Do we just change the days to the number 7 as in the following?date.setTime(date.getTime()+(7*24*60*60*1000));

Comment: When you call `createCookie()`, is accepts as its parameter the number of days, hence the line `createCookie( cookie_name, 1, 7);`. The 1 is the value of the cookie, which is irrelevant for this application as you're just checking if it is present and do not care about the actual value.

Comment: Thanks nickb and it all works fine. So to change the no of days I just change the second parameter to whatever no of days needed!